# Does uninstalling Firefox Snap remove bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, snap, bookmarks

I have uninstalled Firefox Quantum browser previously installed via "Ubuntu Software" on 18.04.2. Does that mean all my profile data is lost altogether with the bookmarks?

I was expecting to find the data in my default profile directory still on the disk so I can copy it to the "vanilla" Firefox installation via apt. Looking for the places.sqlite does show it in the newly installed Firefox profile but not the old Firefox Quantum one.

Comment: **1**: Firefox Quantum is used to describe versions of Firefox 57 onward. So it's better to provide the actual version number. **2**: If you installed the snap version of Firefox, your profile would be within the *snap* folder in your *home* folder. Uninstalling the Firefox snap causes the subfolder containing *~/.mozilla* to be removed as well. So, if you did not previously export/backup your data from the Firefox snap, it's gone.

Comment: Yeah, I used Quantum to reflect that there are two records for Firefox in Ubuntu Software if you install one via apt as well. Thanks for your your answer, it clarifies that. Now, if Snap deletes the profile folder, don't you think it is utterly bad practice to remove user data on uninstall without asking?

Comment: I don't have much experience with snaps. Maybe you could ask another question to address the broader issue of whether/why deleting a snap deletes that snap's user data as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, unlike the Firefox deb package, it erases your profile.

This is despite Mozilla flatly stating that removing Firefox does not remove profiles, with no caveat concerning snap.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately yes. After the upgrade of Ubuntu 20.04 to a new 22.04, I realized that the default web browser was no more pointing to the firefox. The reason was the snap version of the application (instead of the apt based one). I removed the snap version (in order to install the apt based one) and as a side effect I lost all my bookmarks, saved passwords, everything :-(

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the accurate answer because I do not use `snap`, which leaves me with very awful impression.

However, if the folder `~/.mozilla/firefox` exist, then it is very easy to backup your firefox profile, see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles for specific method.